# git log origin/develop gives "fatal: ambiguous argument"

Tags: git, git-log

**Context**: I am making a tool to analyze differences between 2 branches. I would like to watch the history of commits on `origin/develop` and `origin/release`. As I need the history only, I cloned the project with only the history (`git clone --bare`)

After a `git fetch`, I would like to see the latest commits on release and develop without having to `git merge origin/develop|release` on each branch. So I tried to just `git log origin/develop [... format options]`.

On some projects, it works as expected. But on a particular project, I get this error :

```
$ git log origin/develop                                                                                                                                                                                                                 master * ] 11:01 
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/develop': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

If I try `git remote -v`, I can see that `origin` is correctly defined. How could `origin/develop` not be a valid revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [the documentation of the `--bare` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare):

> Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin`

This `git log` option would work if the repository was cloned without the `--bare` flag.

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, this also means you can call `git log <branchname>` directly, without referring to `origin/<branchname>`. I.e., in your case:

```
git log develop
```

Comment: ok, this answers the question, thanks. I will accept it as soon as I can but there is a 5 minutes delay. Do you have any idea how I could track origin/develop without having to clone the whole project ? It seems to me that it should be possible.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You can call `git log <branchname>` directly - see my edited answer